# Separating date and time in a datetime stamp

Tags: database, kdb

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need to find the total sum of amount in say every second or minute interval. I tried using xbar for this but I cannot seem to separate date and time from the data.

Also I'd like to ask how do we add the command for summing up the accounts in the time interval stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; xbar can be used for this grouping. The sum function then can be used to aggregate each group created:

```
select sum Amount by 1 xbar Time.minute from t
```

Or group by the Time column (timestamp is integer based).

```
select sum Amount by Time from t
```

See details below:

If your table is like this:

```
q})t: ([] Amount:`int$(); Time:`timestamp$() );
q)show meta t
c     | t f a
------| -----
Amount| i
Time  | p
```

And using the following data:

```
q)`t insert (10?100;asc .z.p+10?00:10)
q)show t
Amount Time
------------------------------------
58     2017.09.14D10:44:48.992850000
68     2017.09.14D10:44:48.992850000
45     2017.09.14D10:47:48.992850000
2      2017.09.14D10:48:48.992850000
...
```

Then you can use xbar to group the table by each minute interval:

```
q)select sum Amount by 1 xbar Time.minute from t
minute| Amount
------| ------
10:44 | 126
10:47 | 45
10:48 | 41
10:49 | 113
...
```

Or to group by 5 minute intervals:

```
q)select sum Amount by 5 xbar Time.minute from t
minute| Amount
------| ------
10:40 | 126
10:45 | 199
10:50 | 210
```

Or to group by 5 second intervals:

```
q)select sum Amount by 5 xbar Time.second from t
second  | Amount
--------| ------
10:44:45| 126
10:47:45| 45
10:48:45| 41
10:49:45| 113
...
```

The values in the Amount column will be summed for each group.

As a side note, you can also group by distinct values in the Time column:

```
q)select sum Amount by Time from t
Time                         | Amount
-----------------------------| ------
2017.09.14D10:44:48.992850000| 126
2017.09.14D10:47:48.992850000| 45
2017.09.14D10:48:48.992850000| 41
2017.09.14D10:49:48.992850000| 113
2017.09.14D10:51:48.992850000| 122
2017.09.14D10:52:48.992850000| 88
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some catches while using `xbar` and `time`(or `timestamp`) datatype.

1) hourly bucketing the data; you need to cast the time to hour `hh` as `time.hour` is not available in KDB.

```
q)select sum a by 1 xbar `hh$time from t
```

2) bucketing with milli/micro precision, you need to use absolute numbers in the argument.

```
q)select sum a by 1000000  xbar time from t
```